# PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Undefined constant "MB_OVERLOAD_STRING"

Tags: cpanel, joomla3.0

Can someone assist me with this error please. http error 500.

Somehow, I install a new Drupal on a new subdomain, and I remember changing the time zone and region on cPanel, later both our main official website is down and the same with the new subdomain.

So far, this is the only log that I can pull out from our cPanel.

```
2022-03-03 19:05:38.594912 [NOTICE] [3084980] [T0] [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxxx:HTTP2-5#APVH_mise.gov.ki:443] [STDERR] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Undefined constant "MB_OVERLOAD_STRING" in /home/misegov/public_html/libraries/vendor/joomla/string/src/phputf8/utf8.php:38
  thrown in /home/misegov/public_html/libraries/vendor/joomla/string/src/phputf8/utf8.php on line 38
#5 /home/misegov/public_html/index.php(40): require_once('/home/misegov/p...')
#4 /home/misegov/public_html/includes/framework.php(18): require_once('/home/misegov/p...')
#3 /home/misegov/public_html/libraries/cms.php(36): require('/home/misegov/p...')
#2 /home/misegov/public_html/libraries/vendor/autoload.php(7): ComposerAutoloaderInit205c915b9c7d3e718e7c95793ee67ffe::getLoader()
#1 /home/misegov/public_html/libraries/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php(56): composerRequire205c915b9c7d3e718e7c95793ee67ffe()
#0 /home/misegov/public_html/libraries/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php(66): require()
```

Any idea what would be the cause of this please?

Thank you and looking forward for possible solutions on this.

Kind regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to Extensions - Joomla! Update, click Check for Updates and re-install the Joomla core files from the update package.

EDIT: If you cannot access to administrator panel try to reset to PHP 7.x, then update the Joomla to >=3.10.1 after making a backup. Update all extensions beforehand. If necessary Test again with PHP8.

Comment: Thank you so much Alfonso for that, unfortunately the site is not accessible. I can't even get to administrator panel. any idea how to overcome that?

Comment: @TekitaaMautaake do you know which PHP and Joomla version are you using?

Comment: PHP is set to version 8.0

Comment: @TekitaaMautaake PHP 8.0 may be the problem. Reset it to PHP 7.x and try it out. I edited the answer.

Comment: Thanks, version 7.3 solved the problem.